# Outline view in Spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

Many IDEs have an outline panel, something like:

```
classes
   `--- Class A
   |      `-- open()
   |      `-- close()
   `--- Class B
          `-- fun()
functions
   `--- fun1()
   `--- fun2()
```

or something like this. I remember that Spacemacs had something like this (maybe listing of current file tags?), but I cannot find it, I forgot magic key-strokes for it. How to call it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somebody looks for the same, so I will answer to myself, I just found [THIS](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/58lruk/is_there_anything_that_list_the_methods_classes/).